# Safari 6 Debug Console Slow

Tags: javascript, safari

I recently updated to Mountain Lion and Safari 6.0. I am working on a javascript project and writing info to the console. Since moving, the response time has become dramatically slower. It now takes at least several seconds for messages to be written to the console. The same application in Safari 5 or the latest Chrome shows up in near real-time. Any thoughts on resolving this?

Answer (score 2):

I am Debugging in Safari Version 6.0 (7536.25) and printing to the console is terribly slow. Sorry to say this but reminds me of the days when i had firebug lite inside an IE6 app.

Anyways you will be glad to know that you can nighly build of webkit here: http://nightly.webkit.org

Once i got the latest version of webkit I am able to get the same debugger we had in Safari 5. To get it click on Develop -->  Use WebKit Web Inspector.

http://screencast.com/t/db3v9EpbeN

Back to Normalness !!

Answer (score 0):

Safari 6.0 on Lion takes a LOT of real and virtual memory and slows down everything on my MacBook Air, gen 2. I'm wondering whatever happened to the concept of a lite browser.